# Winbind Broken on Reboot In Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, 17.04, hostname

I have installed winbind and libnss-winbind as usual for NetBIOS name resolution on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. This works fine and I can get a response pinging by a random host name on the local network.

Up on reboot however winbind stops resolving NetBIOS names. I can see from `systemctl status winbind` that the service is active and running, and ready to serve connections. Restarting the service fixes the issue but it's broken again on reboot.

Looking at the log doesn't really give any further information.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `Systemctl restart winbind` fixes it? So maybe during your boot up it starts more than one instance and the stop script from winbind kills all started instances and only starts 1. Maybe try to see if there are more than one instance running after a reboot.

Comment: @Ziazis thanks for the suggestion. When I run `systemctl status winbind.service` there are two processes but I think this may be by design as they run under a supervising PID. Restarting the service shows the same two process (albeit with new PIDs). Killing one of those processes makes no difference.

Comment: I rather ment after your reboot, look for winbind via `netstat -tlnp` or something like that to see if it actually is running.

Comment: @Ziazis winbindd shows up and is listening using netstat from `/var/run/samba/winbindd/pipe`. Anyhow, looks like it may be a bug as this is a fresh install. To workaround it I've created a systemd service fixwinbind.service which is working. I'm not happy with it as it's a dirty hack but at least it's working for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same problem and after some search I've found a typo in the `/lib/systemd/system/winbind.service`.

In the `[Unit]` section we've got the line :
`After=network.target nmb.service` but `nmb.service` doesn't exist at all !! So I think that winbind will start too early 'cause `nmb.service` was ignored...

I correct the file, the correct line must be :
`After=network.target nmbd.service` and winbind works after every reboot !!!