# Winbind on Ubuntu 17.04 will not start

Tags: samba, 17.04, services

I apologize in advance as my Linux knowledge is very limited.I've installed Ubuntu 17.04 Server in a test environment and attempted to install Samba. During the installation the winbind daemon will not start. I've ran `apt update && upgrade` before installing Samba however it seems that it didn't help out. I've tested Ubuntu version 16.04 LTS and it works without any errors. I'm a bit lost as to why Winbind will not work on 17.04, Google search results didn't help. If anyone needs more info I'll gladly provide it but you'll probably need to show me the command to do it.

Thank you

```
Jun 14 10:53:18 UbtNicholas systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba Winbind Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit winbind.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit winbind.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jun 14 10:53:18 UbtNicholas systemd[1]: winbind.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 14 10:53:18 UbtNicholas systemd[1]: winbind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 14 10:53:30 UbtNicholas sudo[23772]: nilaberge : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/nilaberge ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su
Jun 14 10:53:30 UbtNicholas sudo[23772]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by nilaberge(uid=0)
Jun 14 10:53:30 UbtNicholas su[23773]: Successful su for root by root
Jun 14 10:53:30 UbtNicholas su[23773]: + /dev/pts/0 root:root
Jun 14 10:53:30 UbtNicholas su[23773]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by nilaberge(uid=0)
Jun 14 10:53:30 UbtNicholas su[23773]: pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
Jun 14 10:53:55 UbtNicholas systemd[1]: Starting Samba Winbind Daemon...
-- Subject: Unit winbind.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit winbind.service has begun starting up.
Jun 14 10:53:55 UbtNicholas systemd[1]: winbind.service: Supervising process 23803 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice
Jun 14 10:53:55 UbtNicholas systemd[1]: winbind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 14 10:53:55 UbtNicholas systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba Winbind Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit winbind.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit winbind.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jun 14 10:53:55 UbtNicholas systemd[1]: winbind.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 14 10:53:55 UbtNicholas systemd[1]: winbind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

There's almost a similar question but the question assumes that it worked on 17.04

Link to the similar question: [Winbind Broken on Reboot In Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920006/winbind-broken-on-reboot-in-ubuntu-17-04)

UPDATE 1: After following andreas advice in running testparm, it found some lines that were old so I've removed them and restarted the winbind service. Still does an error but the systemCTL has found something that might pin point a bit better where the issue is.

```
Jun 26 10:14:29 UbtNicholas winbindd[1493]: [2017/06/26 10:14:29.432130,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd_cache.c:3244(initialize_winbindd_cache)
Jun 26 10:14:29 UbtNicholas winbindd[1493]:   initialize_winbindd_cache: clearing cache and re-creating with version number 2
Jun 26 10:14:29 UbtNicholas winbindd[1493]: [2017/06/26 10:14:29.435598,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd_util.c:892(init_domain_list)
Jun 26 10:14:29 UbtNicholas winbindd[1493]:   Could not fetch our SID - did we join?
Jun 26 10:14:29 UbtNicholas winbindd[1493]: [2017/06/26 10:14:29.436118,  0] ../source3/winbindd/winbindd.c:1401(winbindd_register_handlers)
Jun 26 10:14:29 UbtNicholas winbindd[1493]:   unable to initialize domain list
Jun 26 10:14:29 UbtNicholas systemd[1]: winbind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 26 10:14:29 UbtNicholas systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba Winbind Daemon.
Jun 26 10:14:29 UbtNicholas systemd[1]: winbind.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 26 10:14:29 UbtNicholas systemd[1]: winbind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Run "testparm" and see if it complains about anything in your smb.conf file

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering, I've run testparm command and there's nothing out of the ordinary in it. Besides a few deprecated lines. I've decided to remove those lines anyway and restart the winbind services. It still does an error but the systemctl seems to have found something interesting. I've edited the question with the new information.

Comment: you should paste the output of testparm. It will say some configs are deprecated with a WARNING label, and say they were ignored, but if they are mandatory settings then the net effect is the same as not having specified them, which will be a failure.

Answer (score 0):

Ill just throw this here for anyone having the same problem as me. When you start winbind and it just says "Failed to start Samba Winbind Deamon." you are having a problem whith the log being deprecated and therefore aren't seeing what is really going wrong.

Run testparm (just as andreas said). It will show you a warning about deprecated stuff. What you are looking for is syslog being deprecated. It might not show up at first until you solve other warnings.

'Syslog = 0' should be 'logging = syslog@1 /var/log/samba/log.%m'
Now, when starting winbind you will get a message about what went wrong in journalctl -xe. See: [WARNING "syslog" option is deprecated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867243/warning-syslog-option-is-deprecated) for more information.